# Jquery drop down hover menu only applied to first <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been playing around with trying to get the drop down hover menu to slide down the screen. For some reason, it only works with the first menu item and the others then just appear.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

```js
$('.nav-main li ul').hide().removeClass('.drop-down');
$('.nav-main li').hover(function() {
  $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(1000);
}, function() {
  $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
});
```

```css
.nav-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-main ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Futura W01 Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: inherit;
}
.nav-top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 66px 0 50px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  height: inherit;
}
.nav-top:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child {
  background-image: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.nav-top > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top a:hover,
.nav-top.active a {
  color: #454545;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #00e9d9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top ul {
  /*display: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
}
.nav-top:hover ul {
  /*display: inline;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
  /*-moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out; */
}
.nav-top li {
  float: center;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.nav-top li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -17px;
  width: 22px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
      <ul class="drop-down">
        <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#press">Press</a></li>
        <li><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
        <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="nav-arrow"></span>
</nav>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xtxxk35/)

Comment: The problem is most certainly in your `CSS`.

Comment: Where so? I am pretty new to coding and not too familiar with it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height:inherit;` from `.nav-main ul` and it will solve the problem. The problem exists because the dropdown `.drop-down` inherits the height of the parent li, causing the slide animation to animate just the height of the parent li. I hope it makes sense.

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8xtxxk35/1/)**.

```js
$('.nav-main li ul').hide().removeClass('.drop-down');
$('.nav-main li').hover(
  function() {
    $('ul', this).slideDown(1000);
  },
  function() {
    $('ul', this).slideUp(1000);
  }
);
```

```css
.nav-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-main ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Futura W01 Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
}
.nav-top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 66px 0 50px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  height: inherit;
  /*background: transparent url(../images/nav-divide.png) no-repeat right center;*/
}
.nav-top:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child {
  background-image: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.nav-top > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top a:hover,
.nav-top.active a {
  color: #454545;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #00e9d9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav-top:hover ul {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 1px);
  left: -8.75px;
  width: 105%;
  /*-moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out; */
}
.nav-top li {
  float: center;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  /*
  background: transparent url(../images/nav-divide.png) no-repeat right center;
  background: transparent url(../images/nav-divide.png) no-repeat left center;*/
}
.nav-top li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top:after {
  content: url(../images/nav-divide.png);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -17px;
  width: 22px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
      <ul class="drop-down">
        <li><a href="#about">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#client">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#press">Press</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="nav-arrow"></span>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! So I can learn, would you be able to quickly sum up why that was a problem?

Comment: Sure. The problem happens because the height of `.drop-down` is taken from it's parent `li` which is smaller than it should, so it has to have it's own height. That's why the `slide` animation calculates the animation wrong. That's why that jump from first element to next ones.